# Building clang on Windows - Memory usage

Tags: windows, clang

I am trying to build clang on windows using Visual Studio 2017 and after following the [instructions](https://clang.llvm.org/hacking.html) to create the Visual Studio solution I am having trouble compiling the project. I am getting this error message:

```
C1060: compiler is out of heap space
```

I don't know why the build process would need so much RAM (I have 8GB on my setup) so this makes me think I am doing something worng. Did anyone have this problem?

PS: I tried compiler option *-Zm2000* to increase cache size and got

```
LNK1102: out of memory
```

Funny thing is that precompiled headers seem to be turned off...

Comment: Same issue here. I even used the suggested cmake command to avoid the linker out of memory issue mentioned in getting started "If you are using Visual Studio 2017: cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -Thost=x64 ..\llvm
-Thost=x64 is required, since the 32-bit linker will run out of memory."  From: https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html